# Replace or add code to HTML with CSS

Tags: html, css

It's a challenge and not sure if that's even possible but here is my problem:

I don't have full access to the website. The only what I can do is to edit my external css.

Menu code:

```
<ul id="navPrimary" class="nav">
    <li id="navLink1"><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I want to add this as first position on the list:

```
<li id="navHome"><a href="/"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>
```

I can ask system administrator to add link to Home but his code will look like this:

```
<li id="navHome"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

So there still will be the problem with replacing text `Home` with my `<i class="icon-home"></i>`.

The only thing which comes up to my mind regarding CSS is `:before`, `:after` and `content` but not quite sure how exactly to use it. As before I've tried adding single word.

**EDIT1**

I have tired this:

`#navLink1:before{
content:'<li id="navHome"><a href="/"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>';
}`

but this added only html code as text.

Comment: google is your friend http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Comment: HTML in content attribute doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do so without using pseudo elements you can just hide the link text and add the icon as a background. To remove the text you do

```
  display: inline-block; /* or block */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
```

Then add the background as an image, sample:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOYmoQ

This still requires the admin to add the link in for you.

Comment: This it the only available solution. Working perfect.

Answer (score 2):

by using :before and :after you can add content to your HTML document. even you can add a icon too.

**for eg**

```
#navHome:before {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:20px;  /* this must be the icon width*/
  height:20px; /* this must be the icon height*/
  background: url(icon.png) 0 0  not-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This works visually but, he needs the link to go home.

Comment: As the OP mentioned "I can ask system administrator to add link to Home but his code will look like this:" The only issue is the icon which can be done with css

Comment: Ah @Huangism thanks, in that case then there's no need for pseudo elements.

Comment: Yes this can be done with just the anchor itself but I think this answer is still good since the OP asked for before and after